# Angular: how to make localStorage works async

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

I trying to get data when I log in, by sending ID from localStorage. Everything I tried didn't work, and the only thing comes to my mind is that getting ID from local storage works synchronously. I hope someone can help me make it async. Unfortunately, I don't have permission to show API here. The code: 
**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { throwError, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Restaurant } from '../models/Restaurant';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  loginUrl = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
  errorData: {};


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  redirectUrl: string;

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    var postData = {email: email, password: password};
    return this.http.post<Restaurant>(this.loginUrl, postData)
    .pipe(map(restaurant => {
        if (restaurant) {
          localStorage.setItem('currentRestaurant', JSON.stringify(restaurant));
          return  restaurant;
        }
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }

  isLoggedIn() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('currentRestaurant')) {
      return true;
    }
      return false;
  }

  getAuthorizationToken() {
    const currentRestaurant = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentRestaurant'));
    return currentRestaurant.token;
  }

  logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentRestaurant');
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {

      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {

      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
      console.error(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` + `body was: ${error.error}`);
    }

    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    this.errorData = {
      errorTitle: 'Oops! Request for document failed',
      errorDesc: 'Something bad happened. Please try again later.'
    };
    return throwError(this.errorData);
  }

  currRestaurant: Restaurant = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentRestaurant'));
  currID = this. currRestaurant.id;
}
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  loginForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  error: {};
  loginError: string;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this.fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.authService.logout();
  }

  get email() { return this.loginForm.get('email'); }
  get password() { return this.loginForm.get('password'); }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.authService.login( this.email.value, this.password.value).subscribe((data) => {

       if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
            const redirect = this.authService.redirectUrl ? this.authService.redirectUrl : '/';
                this.router.navigate([redirect]);
      } else {
            this.loginError = 'email or password is incorrect.';
    }
      },
      error => this.error = error
    );

  }

}
```

Thanks everyone for their time

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/angular-async-local-storage

Comment: @FatehMohamed I tried to follow along, but have many troubles with it

Comment: Could you please clearify, what your actual error is? You are running this code, and this.authService.isLoggedIn never evaluates to true or is it something else? Since you are accessing the localStorage inside your subscribe the async/sync should not be the problem. Maybe you could create a minimal working example as a stackblitz. Furthermore, not too sure whether it's just a mistake inside your question, but ```isLoggedIn``` is a function, shouldn't you call ```this.authService.isLoggedIn() ``` inside your subscribe?

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes:

1. Are you aware that you use Native `localStorage`, not the one you import - `import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';` (and also it should be injected in the `constructor` if you want to use it, and used in asynchronous way)
2. `if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {` will always be true, because `this.authService.isLoggedIn` is a **function** and it is not a falsy value. You probably want to execute it - `if (this.authService.isLoggedIn()) {`
3. `redirectUrl` is always undefined because your provided snippets does not assign it any value.